# nHibernate Projections.Sum for joined columns

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I am creating a query with Criteria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria auftragCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Auftrag>("a");
```

I join multiple tables with:

```
DetachedCriteria positionJoin = auftragCriteria.CreateCriteria("a.Positionen", "p", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

And I use a projection to fill in my object `SubTypeAuftrag`

```
ProjectionList projectionListSubTypeAuftrag = Projections.ProjectionList();
```

Now I need to recreate the following sql code:

```
cast(sum(p.length * p.width / 1000) as decimal)
```

I tried the following:

```
projectionListSubTypeAuftrag.Add(Projections.Sum<Position>(p => p.length * p.width / 1000), "M1");
```

This leads to an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable 'p' of type 'xxx.Base.Position' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'
```

I also tried:

```
        projectionListSubTypeAuftrag.Add(
            Projections.Cast(
                NHibernateUtil.Decimal,
                Projections.SqlProjection("p.length * p.width/ 1000 AS result", new[] { "result" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Double })
                ),
            "M1"
            );
```

How can I tell nHibernate where to find the length/width column?

Comment: `Projections.Sum<Position>(p => p.length * p.width / 1000)` will work in 5.3 when released

Comment: okay, hope so, this would be awesome

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin is there a work around for the current version?

Comment: Yeah - writing own projection... Or you may try using development builds https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2251#issuecomment-626687676

Answer (score 0):

Maybee this will point you in the right direction.

```
  var sqlMultiply = new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "*", ")");
            var sqlDivide = new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "/", ")");
            var multiplyLengthWidthProj = Projections.SqlFunction(sqlMultiply, NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Property(() => alias.Length), Projections.Property(() => alias.Width));

            var sumProjection = Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.SqlFunction(sqlDivide, NHibernateUtil.Decimal, multiplyLengthWidthProj, Projections.Constant(1000))));
```